# Difference between "Repick" and "Back to browsing"

Tags: dota-2

In Dota, you can pick a hero. You have the option to "Repick", which has a red X in it, signifying something bad.

However, you can also choose "Return to browsing" which just has cards, which looks less evil-ish imo. Is there a difference either way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you repick, you're forced to choose another hero. This costs you 100 gold and then you choose again.

Returning to browsing just lets you browse the hero list.